# Does it make sense to use survey::svydesign and tbl_svysummary after full matching to account for matching weights?

Tags: r, matching, gtsummary

I do full matching with the MatchIt package in R, which gives me the weights for each observation in the matched dataset. I then want to present a summary table of the outcomes for the treatment and the control group.

I cannot use the normal tbl_summary from the gtsummary package by Sjoberg as it does not account for matching weights. So, I thought I might use tbl_svysummary (survey package) because it would allow me to account for matching weights.

Thus, my code would look like:

Extract<-matched_data %>% select(outcome, Treatment, weights)

survey::svydesign(~1, data = as.data.frame(Extract), weights = ~weights) %>%
tbl_svysummary(by=Treatment,digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0, 2))) %>% add_p()

My question: Does that make sense? Or how can I present a summary table after full matching that allows me to account for the matching weights?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Yes, this is a very common workflow (using the survey package to create a weighted data object). Happy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

You can go about it that way, however, I work with survey data regularly and in my experience its easier to use the survey::svymean() or survey::svyby() functions when I want to present summary tables.

So for example using svyby:

`svyby(~ Treatment, ~ outcome, design = YOURDESIGN, svymean)`

Please refer to the documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.1-1/topics/svyby

[The book 'complex surveys' by Lumley](https://www.wiley.com/en-be/Complex+Surveys%3A+A+Guide+to+Analysis+Using+R-p-9781118210932) is also a great resource to read and learn more about survey designs and also summarising your results in easy ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, the thing is, I don't have survey data. I have observational clinic data, und I do propensity score matching (full matching) for the treatment and control group. As I want to compare the outcomes of interest for the two groups, and as I have weights from full matching, I was looking for a package to generate nice summary tables which can take account of the weights. I was unsure if I could use the survey package for that purpose, or if there is a better package available.

Comment: Hi! Yes, the Survey package is definitely made for weighted data (not always exclusively for survey data), so it would be relevant for your case -- you also specified the weights in the svydesign from your example, so all analyses will take those weights into account.